# stuck on infinite for-loop of dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python trying to build an app that randomly generates strings to match a given string. Each time a string is generated, it compares the generated string with given string, and if the alphabet is correct, the next generation will keep the correct alphabets until the entire string matches.

I don't even know if I need a dictionary, but I am stuck on the `for` loop in the `generateString` function. How do I fix it so it will print all the generated strings until it is correct?

Here's my code:

```
import random

def generateString(strlen):

    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    result = ""
    for i in range(strlen):
        result+=alphabet[random.randrange(27)]
    for key in dict:
        result[key[i]]= [dict['key']]
    return result

def score(goalstring,resultstring):

    numscore = 0
    for i in range(len(goalstring)):
        if goalstring[i] == resultstring[i]:
            numscore+=1
    return float(numscore/len(goalstring))

def main():

    goalstring = "how long will it take to generate this"
    beststring = generateString(38)
    dict = {}
    while score(goalstring,beststring)<1:
        newstring = generateString(38)
        if score(goalstring,newstring)>score(goalstring,beststring):
            for i in range(len(goalstring)):
                if goalstring[i] == beststring[i]:
                    dict['i']=goalstring[i]                 
            beststring=newstring    
        print beststring

main()
```

Comment: "I am stuck on the for loop in the generateString function." Which one? generateString() has two.

Comment: the second one. i cant seem to update the correct alphabets into the newly generated string

Comment: from `dict['key']` remove the quotes and try. That is write it is `dict[key]`